# Puppeteer: wait for request to finish after dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

I am writing a test for my React application.

I have two dropdowns. Once a selection is made in the first one, a fetch request is trigged and the data from that fetch request is used to populate the second dropdown.

My test looks like this:

```
test("fruit dropdown becomes enabled when food type fruit is selected", async () => {
  await page.select('[data-testid="food"]', "fruit"); // this makes a selection in the drop down and fires a request

  // I should wait for request to finish before doing this
  const isFruitDropdownDisabled = await page.$eval(
    '[data-testid="fruit"]',
    element => element.disabled
  );

  expect(isFruitDropdownDisabled).toBe(false);
}, 16000);
```

Right now that test fails, how do I tell it to wait until the fetch request has finished before checking if `[data-testid="fruit"]` is disabled?

Comment: I think you forgot to write what the question was, but I assume that the `expect` fails because the dropdown hasn't rendered yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Wait until the request/response is finished
2. Wait until the second dropdown box is filled

**Option 1: Wait for the request**

Use [`page.waitForResponse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.17.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) to wait for a specific response to happen, before you want your script to continue. Example:

```js
await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('/part-of-the-url'));
```

**Option 2: Wait for the second dropdown box to be filled**

As you are saying that the request populates another dropdown box (I'm guessing a `select` element), you could use the [`page.waitForFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.17.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) function to wait until the select box is filled. Example:

```js
await page.waitForFunction(() => document.querySelector('#selector-of-second-selectbox').length > 0);
```

The `length` attribute on a select box will check how many `option` elements are inside. So by checking if `length` is non-zero, this is wait until the select box is filled. This assumes, that the select box is empty at the start (`length` is `0`).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait for something, use one of the `waitFor`-functions described in the manual, such as [waitForFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args).

Comment: Not sure how this would work, so in my `App.jsx` I have a function called `getFruit` that goes and does the fetch request, are you saying I can do `page.waitForFunction('getFruit');` That fails with the message `getFruit` is undefined.

Comment: `page.waitForFunction('getFruit');` doesn't make much sense--it translates into running the literal code `getFruit` in the browser. You should provide a function or a stringified function body. Maybe select `[data-testid="fruit"]` and block until it's disabled: `page.waitForFunction(\`document.querySelector('[data-testid="fruit"]').disabled\`)`. I'm not sure if that'll help with your test, but might be handy for future visitors.